# if two people have same score how to return both names connected by "and"

Tags: python

I'm calculating the average score of people in a dictionary with two-dimensional array and I want to know how to return two people with the same score connected by "and"; EX: name and name

My code:

```
def bestAverage(inputDict):
    dic = {}
    for i in inputDict:
        if i[0] in dic.keys():
            dic[i[0]].append(int(i[1]))
        else:
            dic[i[0]] = [int(i[1])]
    totle_score = 0
    print(dic)
    for key, value, in dic.items():
        for c in value:
         totle_score += int(c)
        Q = len(value)
        avrage = totle_score / Q
        dic[key]= [avrage]
    print(dic)
```

My input:

```
inputDict = [ ["Diane", 20],["Bion",25],["Jack","30"],["Diane","50"] ]
result = bestAverage(inputDict)
```

OUTCOME:

```
{'Diane': [35.0], 'Bion': [95.0], 'Jack': [125.0]}
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Please post your input to make [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hint: check if the values are same, if they are. Try changing the key name with a `and ` afterwards.

Comment: Need to see your input

Comment: I added my input.

Answer (score 0):

Using the sorted dictionary, you can get the dictionary you want.
Sorry, I think my code is a bit complicated.

```
dic = {'Diane': [35.0], 
       'Bion': [95.0], 
       'Jack': [125.0], 
       'Diane_2': [35.0], 
       'Bion_2':[95], 
       'Diane_3':[35.0], 
       'John':[10]}

import operator

sorted_dic = sorted(dic.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))
new_dic = dict()
preKey = sorted_dic[0][0]
preValue = sorted_dic[0][1]
nms = preKey
for key,value in sorted_dic[1:]:
    if(value == preValue):
        nms  += ' and ' + key
    else:
        new_dic[nms] = preValue
        preKey = key
        preValue = value
        nms = preKey
new_dic[nms] = preValue

print(new_dic)
```

OUTCOME:

> {'Jack': [125.0], 'John': [10], 'Diane and Diane_2 and Diane_3':
>   [35.0], 'Bion and Bion_2': [95.0]}

Answer (score 0):

Per the OPs question in the comments, this example now produces a final structure containing entries for only those scores that had multiple people with that same score.

```
data = {'Diane': [35.0], 'Bion': [95.0], 'Jack': [125.0], 'Sam': [95.0]}

# Here, we create a dict of lists, where the keys are the scores, and the values
# are the names of each person who has that score.  This will produce:
#
# {
#     35.0: ['Diane'],
#     95.0: ['Bion', 'Sam'],
#     125.0: ['Jack']
#  }

collected = {}

# For each key (name) in the input dict...
for name in data:
    # Get the score value out of the array for this name
    val = data[name][0]

    # If we don't have an entry in our new dict for this score (no key in the dict of that
    # score value) then add that entry as the score for the key and an empty array for the value
    if val not in collected:
        collected[val] = []

    # Now that we're sure we have an entry for the score of the name we're processing, add
    # the name to the array for that score in the new dict
    collected[val].append(name)

# Now we just "flip" each entry in the 'collected' map to create a new dict.  We create
# one entry in this dict for each entry in the 'collected' map, where each key is a
# single string where we've combined all of the names with the same score, separated
# by 'and', and each value is the score that those names had.

result = {}

# Now iterate over each of our keys, the unique scores, in our new 'collected' dict...
for val in collected:

    # We only want to create an entry in the new dict if the entry we're processing has more than
    # just one name in the list of names.  So here, we check for that, and skip adding an entry to
    # the new dict if there is only one name in the list
    if len(collected[val]) == 1:
        continue

    # Combine the value of this entry, the list of names with a particular score, into a single string
    combinedNames = " and ".join(collected[val])

    # Add an entry to our 'result' dict with this combined name as the key and the score as the value
    result[combinedNames] = val

# Print each combined name string from the resulting structure
for names in result:
    print(names)
```

Output:

```
Bion and Sam
```

Comment: how can only get "Bion and Sam" without the other names and numbers?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  You can see the code.  I'll add some comments.

Comment: If you are having trouble understanding the code, "run" the code in your own head...follow each step, and iterate in each of the loops.  Write down what is happening on a piece of paper, building up the structures that are being built.  After a while, you'll be able to do that in reverse...think about what you want, and then work backwards to write the code that produces what you want.

Comment: How can I only get the names of people with the same score? Ex: Output: Bion and Sam. instead of  {'Bion and Sam': 95.0, 'Diane': 35.0, 'Jack': 125.0}

Comment: Oh.  That's easy.  Just put a condition in based on the size of the list of names. Don't add an entry to the new dict if the list only has one item.  I'll put that in the code.  Please tell me if that was what you wanted.

Comment: with this code, the OUTPUT= Jack    Where it should be two names or none? we're getting closer haha

Comment: Huh? With which code?  With my code above?  My code prints just what I showed in the answer..."Bion and Sam". - I just copied the text right out of this window, pasted it into my IDE, and ran it again, just to make sure.